# About Google Calendar Push Notification

Tags: java, push-notification, calendar, google-calendar-api

Dear Google Calendar Team,

I want to develop Push Notification for calendar. I have gone through the article

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push

But I have couple of questions:-

Can we register local host as a receiving url.

How to Register the domain.

What does chanel means in this context?

Can you share a sample which can show working push notification of calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we register local host as a receiving url.

No, you can't. The Google API sends HTTPS `POST` messages, and for the HTTPS to work it needs a SSL certificate pointing to your domain.

> How to Register the domain.

There are no specific requisites about domain registration. You should register it following the usual procedures. Please remember to perform a domain verification on the Cloud Console after the registration.

> What does chanel means in this context?

A *channel* configures the path for your push notifications. It contains the URL where you will receive the messages and notification settings. A channel is set to listen to one *resource* (i.e. a Calendar resource). When the resource gets updated, the Google API will send a HTTPS `POST` message to your channel URL.

> Can you share a sample which can show working push notification of
> calendar?

There are many different examples on the linked docs. If you need help on a particular topic, please be more specific about the related step.